# Jssor slider loading time

Tags: carousel, jssor

I have added multiple instances of "jssor slider" for product carousel in a single page, its working fine but when I refresh the page it takes a lot of time to load the carousel on homepage how can I reduce the loading time of carousel?

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Carousel Demo - Jssor Slider, Carousel, Slideshow with Javascript Source Code</title>
</head>
<body style="font-family:Arial, Verdana;background-color:#fff;">
    <!-- it works the same with all jquery version from 1.x to 2.x -->
    <script type="text/javascript" src="examples/js/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>
    <!-- use jssor.slider.mini.js (40KB) instead for release -->
    <!-- jssor.slider.mini.js = (jssor.js + jssor.slider.js) -->
    <script type="text/javascript" src="examples/js/jssor.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="examples/js/jssor.slider.js"></script>
    <script>
        jQuery(document).ready(function ($) {
            var options = {
                $AutoPlay: true,                                    //[Optional] Whether to auto play, to enable slideshow, this option must be set to true, default value is false
                $AutoPlaySteps: 1,                                  //[Optional] Steps to go for each navigation request (this options applys only when slideshow disabled), the default value is 1
                $AutoPlayInterval: 4000,                            //[Optional] Interval (in milliseconds) to go for next slide since the previous stopped if the slider is auto playing, default value is 3000
                $PauseOnHover: 1,                               //[Optional] Whether to pause when mouse over if a slider is auto playing, 0 no pause, 1 pause for desktop, 2 pause for touch device, 3 pause for desktop and touch device, 4 freeze for desktop, 8 freeze for touch device, 12 freeze for desktop and touch device, default value is 1

                $ArrowKeyNavigation: true,                  //[Optional] Allows keyboard (arrow key) navigation or not, default value is false
                $SlideDuration: 160,                                //[Optional] Specifies default duration (swipe) for slide in milliseconds, default value is 500
                $MinDragOffsetToSlide: 20,                          //[Optional] Minimum drag offset to trigger slide , default value is 20
                $SlideWidth: 200,                                   //[Optional] Width of every slide in pixels, default value is width of 'slides' container
                //$SlideHeight: 150,                                //[Optional] Height of every slide in pixels, default value is height of 'slides' container
                $SlideSpacing: 3,                      //[Optional] Space between each slide in pixels, default value is 0
                $DisplayPieces: 4,                                  //[Optional] Number of pieces to display (the slideshow would be disabled if the value is set to greater than 1), the default value is 1
                $ParkingPosition: 0,                              //[Optional] The offset position to park slide (this options applys only when slideshow disabled), default value is 0.
                $UISearchMode: 1,                                   //[Optional] The way (0 parellel, 1 recursive, default value is 1) to search UI components (slides container, loading screen, navigator container, arrow navigator container, thumbnail navigator container etc).
                $PlayOrientation: 1,                                //[Optional] Orientation to play slide (for auto play, navigation), 1 horizental, 2 vertical, 5 horizental reverse, 6 vertical reverse, default value is 1
                $DragOrientation: 1,                                //[Optional] Orientation to drag slide, 0 no drag, 1 horizental, 2 vertical, 3 either, default value is 1 (Note that the $DragOrientation should be the same as $PlayOrientation when $DisplayPieces is greater than 1, or parking position is not 0)

                $BulletNavigatorOptions: {                                //[Optional] Options to specify and enable navigator or not
                    $Class: $JssorBulletNavigator$,                       //[Required] Class to create navigator instance
                    $ChanceToShow: 2,                               //[Required] 0 Never, 1 Mouse Over, 2 Always
                    $AutoCenter: 0,                                 //[Optional] Auto center navigator in parent container, 0 None, 1 Horizontal, 2 Vertical, 3 Both, default value is 0
                    $Steps: 1,                                      //[Optional] Steps to go for each navigation request, default value is 1
                    $Lanes: 1,                                      //[Optional] Specify lanes to arrange items, default value is 1
                    $SpacingX: 0,                                   //[Optional] Horizontal space between each item in pixel, default value is 0
                    $SpacingY: 0,                                   //[Optional] Vertical space between each item in pixel, default value is 0
                    $Orientation: 1                                 //[Optional] The orientation of the navigator, 1 horizontal, 2 vertical, default value is 1
                },

                $ArrowNavigatorOptions: {
                    $Class: $JssorArrowNavigator$,              //[Requried] Class to create arrow navigator instance
                    $ChanceToShow: 1,                               //[Required] 0 Never, 1 Mouse Over, 2 Always
                    $AutoCenter: 2,                                 //[Optional] Auto center navigator in parent container, 0 None, 1 Horizontal, 2 Vertical, 3 Both, default value is 0
                    $Steps: 1                                       //[Optional] Steps to go for each navigation request, default value is 1
                }
            };

            var jssor_slider1 = new $JssorSlider$('slider1_container', options);

            //responsive code begin
            //you can remove responsive code if you don't want the slider scales while window resizes
            function ScaleSlider() {
                var bodyWidth = document.body.clientWidth;
                if (bodyWidth)
                    jssor_slider1.$ScaleWidth(Math.min(bodyWidth, 809));
                else
                    window.setTimeout(ScaleSlider, 30);
            }
            ScaleSlider();

            $(window).bind("load", ScaleSlider);
            $(window).bind("resize", ScaleSlider);
            $(window).bind("orientationchange", ScaleSlider);
            //responsive code end
        });
    </script>
    <!-- Jssor Slider Begin -->
    <!-- To move inline styles to css file/block, please specify a class name for each element. --> 
    <div id='slider1_container' style="position: relative; top: 0px; left: 0px; width: 100%; height: 350px; overflow: hidden;">

        <!-- Loading Screen -->
        <div u="loading" style="position: absolute; top: 0px; left: 0px;">
            <div style="filter: alpha(opacity=70); opacity:0.7; position: relative; display: block;
                background-color: #000; top: 0px; left: 0px;width: 100%;height:100%;">
            </div>
            <div style="position: absolute; display: block; background: url(examples/img/loading.gif) no-repeat center center;
                top: 0px; left: 0px;width: 100%;height:100%;">
            </div>
        </div>

        <!-- Slides Container -->
        <div u="slides" style="cursor: move; position: absolute; left: 100px; top: 0px; width: 100%; height: 350px; overflow: hidden;">
            


<?php $i=0; foreach ($_products->getItems() as $_product): ?>
<?php $_products = $this->getProductCollection(); ?>
<?php $_collectionSize = sizeof($_products); ?>
<?php $_columnCount = Mage::getStoreConfig('homepage/options/count'); ?>

<div class="block-content" >

        <?php if (sizeof($_products)): ?>
           
                <?php if ($i++%$_columnCount==10): ?>
                <ul class="products-grid">
                <?php endif ?>

                        <?php // echo $_product->getData('is_salable') . Mage::getStoreConfig('homepage/options/salable');  ?>
                        <?php if ($_product->getData('is_salable')): ?>
                            <li class="item<?php if($i==sizeof($_products) ): ?> last<?php endif; ?>">
                                <a href="<?php echo $_product->getProductUrl() ?>" title="<?php echo $this->htmlEscape($_product->getName()) ?>" class="product-image"><img src="<?php echo $this->helper('catalog/image')->init($_product, 'thumbnail')->resize(1930); ?>" width="100%" height="140" alt="" /></a>
                                <div class="product-details">
                                    <p class="product-name"><a href="<?php echo $this->getProductUrl($_product) ?>"><?php echo $this->htmlEscape($_product->getName()) ?></a></p>
                                    <?php if (Mage::getStoreConfig('homepage/options/price')):?>
                                        <?php echo $this->getPriceHtml($_product, true) ?>
                                    <?php endif; ?>
                                    <?php if (Mage::getStoreConfig('homepage/options/actions')):?>
                                        <a class="link-cart" href="<?php echo $this->getAddToCartUrl($_product) ?>" title="<?php echo $this->htmlEscape($_product->getName()) ?>"><?php echo $this->__('Add to Cart') ?></a>
                                    <?php endif; ?>
                                </div>
                            </li>
                        <?php else: ?>
                            <?php if( Mage::getStoreConfig('homepage/options/salable')) : ?>
                                <li class="item">
                                    <a href="<?php echo $_product->getProductUrl() ?>" title="<?php echo $this->htmlEscape($_product->getName()) ?>" class="product-image"><img src="<?php echo $this->helper('catalog/image')->init($_product, 'thumbnail')->resize(1930); ?>" width="130" height="130" alt="" /></a>
                                    <div class="product-details">
                                        <p class="product-name"><a href="<?php echo $this->getProductUrl($_product) ?>"><?php echo $this->htmlEscape($_product->getName()) ?></a></p>
                                        <?php if (Mage::getStoreConfig('homepage/options/price')):?>
                                            <?php echo $this->getPriceHtml($_product, true) ?>
                                        <?php endif; ?>
                                        <?php if (Mage::getStoreConfig('homepage/options/actions')):?>
                                            <a class="link-cart" href="<?php echo $this->getAddToCartUrl($_product) ?>" title="<?php echo $this->htmlEscape($_product->getName()) ?>"><?php echo $this->__('Add to Cart ') ?></a>
                                        <?php endif; ?>
                                    </div>
                                </li>
                            <?php endif; ?>
                        <?php endif; ?>

                <?php if ($i%$_columnCount==0 || $i==$_collectionSize): ?>
                </ul>
                <?php endif ?>
            


        <?php else: ?>
            <ol id="bestseller-sidebar" class="mini-products-list">
                <li class="item odd">
                    <?php echo Mage::getStoreConfig('homepage/options/noproduct') ?>
                </li>
            </ol>
        <?php endif; ?>

    </div>
<?php endforeach; ?>

        </div>
        
        <!--#region Bullet Navigator Skin Begin -->
        <!-- Help: http://www.jssor.com/development/slider-with-bullet-navigator-jquery.html -->
        <style>
            /* jssor slider bullet navigator skin 03 css */
            /*
            .jssorb03 div           (normal)
            .jssorb03 div:hover     (normal mouseover)
            .jssorb03 .av           (active)
            .jssorb03 .av:hover     (active mouseover)
            .jssorb03 .dn           (mousedown)
            */
            .jssorb03 {
                position: absolute;
            }
            .jssorb03 div, .jssorb03 div:hover, .jssorb03 .av {
                position: absolute;
                /* size of bullet elment */
                width: 21px;
                height: 21px;
                text-align: center;
                line-height: 21px;
                color: white;
                font-size: 12px;
                background: url(examples/img/b03.png) no-repeat;
                overflow: hidden;
                cursor: pointer;
            }
            .jssorb03 div { background-position: -5px -4px; }
            .jssorb03 div:hover, .jssorb03 .av:hover { background-position: -35px -4px; }
            .jssorb03 .av { background-position: -65px -4px; }
            .jssorb03 .dn, .jssorb03 .dn:hover { background-position: -95px -4px; }
        </style>
        <!-- bullet navigator container -->
        
        <!--#endregion Bullet Navigator Skin End -->
        
        <!--#region Arrow Navigator Skin Begin -->
        <!-- Help: http://www.jssor.com/development/slider-with-arrow-navigator-jquery.html -->
        <style>
            /* jssor slider arrow navigator skin 03 css */
            /*
            .jssora03l                  (normal)
            .jssora03r                  (normal)
            .jssora03l:hover            (normal mouseover)
            .jssora03r:hover            (normal mouseover)
            .jssora03l.jssora03ldn      (mousedown)
            .jssora03r.jssora03rdn      (mousedown)
            */
            .jssora03l, .jssora03r {
                display: block;
                position: absolute;
                /* size of arrow element */
                width: 55px;
                height: 55px;
                cursor: pointer;
                background: url(examples/img/a03.png) no-repeat;
                overflow: hidden;
            }
            .jssora03l { background-position: -3px -33px; }
            .jssora03r { background-position: -63px -33px; }
            .jssora03l:hover { background-position: -123px -33px; }
            .jssora03r:hover { background-position: -183px -33px; }
            .jssora03l.jssora03ldn { background-position: -243px -33px; }
            .jssora03r.jssora03rdn { background-position: -303px -33px; }
        </style>
        <!-- Arrow Left -->
        <span u="arrowleft" class="jssora03l" style="top: 123px; left: 8px;">
        </span>
        <!-- Arrow Right -->
        <span u="arrowright" class="jssora03r" style="top: 123px; right: 8px;">
        </span>
        <!--#endregion Arrow Navigator Skin End -->
        <a style="display: none" href="http://www.jssor.com">Bootstrap Slider</a>
    </div>
    <!-- Jssor Slider End -->
</body>
</html>
```